# ssh error during cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a problem with deploying an application with cap.

```
** Execute git:wrapper
 INFO [bd212f0d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/webiaprod/ on 91.236.254.28
DEBUG [bd212f0d] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/webiaprod/
cap aborted!
patatoid
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `ssh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:122:in `block in _execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:119:in `tap'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:119:in `_execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
```

It may be a problem with ssh but I can't figure out where it is from...

Comment: Can you ssh to the machine you are deploying to from the machine you are deploying from?  Are the credentials ok? is the public key from the machine you are deploying from in the authorized_keys of the machine/user you are deploying to?

Comment: I can just say that I can ssh the machine I am deploying to... What about the credentials?

Comment: By credentials I meant using the right user in your cap config for example `server 'myserver.com' roles: [:web], user: 'myuser'`. Make you can ssh to `myuser` on the machine you are deploying to,

Comment: got the right user, still not working...

Comment: can that user run `mkdir -p /tmp/webiaprod/` with no problems ?

Comment: yep, pretty sure that it is a connexion problem

Comment: Try a different host and see if it's host specific or cap configuration.

Comment: thx for answer :) it may be cap config...

Comment: Np. Can you thumbs up some of the comments ? :-)

Comment: thummbs? u want my cap config?

Comment: No dude, thumbs up on the comments on this website (StackOverflow)

Comment: hence no clue for my problem?